# webpack es6 module not found

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am new to webpack, want to bundle my js classes 
I am using es6 classes and linqjs.min, jquery-3.4.1.js and gsap.min
for starter I want only to bundle index.js and my class but I get an error
Module not found: cant resolve (myclass) in src directory
in my index.js for importing class:

```
import myClass from 'js/myClass'
```

and for exporting my class I used

`export class myClass{ }` and 
`module.export= myClass`

my webpack.config.js is:

```
const HTMLWebPackPlugin = require ('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
module:{
    rules:[
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            use:{
                loader:"babel-loader"
            }
        },
        {
            test:/\.html$/,
            use:[{
                loader:"html-loader",
                options:{minimize:true}
            }]
        }
    ]
},
plugins:[
    new HTMLWebPackPlugin({
        template:"./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html"
    })
]}
```

I don't understand my mistake how can I fix it. Thanks.

Comment: As your question stands, it is impossible to answer. Please share details about how you try to import your class, and about the folder structure, as well as your `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: @connexo you are right but since I have little information about this topic I didnt know how to describe it

Comment: Try using `resolve.modules`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I trşed to use your suggection but still the module error.
I think I used import and export myClass wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do a default import, whereas you are doing a named export.

Either go with a **default** export, adding the `default` keyword:

```
export default class MyClass {}
```

along with

```
import MyClass from './js/MyClass.js';
```

Or, go with a **named** export / import:

```
export class MyClass {}
```

with

```
import { MyClass } from './js/MyClass.js';
```

Please note that by convention, class names start with a capital letter.

Medium has a good article on the difference: https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: normally my class name is TextAnimation I just write myClass in example but thanks

Comment: I used your second option and works great thanks forgot to use { } for my class